# Why seconds and minutes do not calculate properly in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, time

I'm currently creating a CI project and i faced the folowing issue.
I want to show "posted "X" time ago" text and i found a script online but the seconds and minutes are not properly shown.

I've already searched all over the net but i couldn't find anything.

Here's my function:

```
$today = time();
$createdday = mysql_to_unix($ptime); 
$datediff = abs($today - $createdday);
$difftext = "";
$years = floor($datediff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
$months = floor(($datediff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (30 * 60 * 60 * 24));
$days = floor(($datediff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60 * 24));
$hours = floor($datediff / 3600);
$minutes = floor($datediff / 60);
$seconds = floor($datediff);
```

Here's the full pastebin https://pastebin.com/tzBN2gZW

Any thoughts on that?

Thanks

Comment: Whats the function `mysql_to_unix` ?

Comment: @Raymond it converts the mysql timestamp to unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occured because you don't reduce datediff after days counting. But I think it's more suitable to use DateTime objects for such calculating

```
$today = time();
$createdday = mysql_to_unix($ptime);
$today_d = new DateTime();
$today_d->setTimestamp($today);
$createdday_d = new DateTime();
$createdday_d->setTimestamp($createdday);
print_r($today_d->diff($createdday_d));
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/1055743)

Comment: SInce i'm new in that does it work in other languages too right?!

Comment: As you can see, DateInterval Object contains only digits.

Comment: It works ok! I just wanted to study it more! Thank you very much!

Comment: Well there's still something wrong.. It does not calculate the minutes and the first hours correctly as i can see..
e.g.: one entry was posted 1 hour and 33' ago, and i only get the 33 minutes.
Same in something that's posted in less than 1 hour ago..
The others though are working correctly (i think)..
Any thoughts?!
https://pastebin.com/q9tdsMRR

Comment: I've tried to give you an example of the last timestamp that gets faulty time ago calculation.

Comment: I' ll use your first suggestion that worked fine! I think there's something wrong with the minutes and seconds calculations since i get wrong data in array too! 

Thanks for your help and your time! I appreciate it!